# How can I create a StorageFile object from URI?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm working on a HTML+JS app.
I have to launch image file from Internet in native photo app.

Code to launch:

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://someuri.com/somefile.JPG");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(
      function (file) {
          // Launch the retrieved file using the default app
          Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).then(
            function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    // File launched
                } else {
                    // File launch failed
                }
            }
          );
      }
    );
```

There is problem with **file** variable should be a [StorageFile class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx). I can't create this class from URI. Which method should I choose (look into link)?

Method **getFileFromApplicationUriAsync** only gets files from other application, not from web.
Method **createStreamedFileFromUriAsync** isn't available on WP 8.1.
Method **getFileFromPathAsync** doesn't support URIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid your only option is to download the file to local storage, and then go from there.

Comment: You could also just launch the HTTP URL as well, although it will open in the browser.